# Issue with clang-tidy and mingw

Tags: c, mingw, clang-tidy

I dont know if this is the correct place to ask, but i am having some problems with clang-tidy and mingw on windows.

Everything is working fine compiling with gcc and checking with clang-tidy. Except once i add "unistd" (for sleep). In that case it still compiles and runs perfectly fine with gcc. But First clang-tidy does not find the relevant header files and if i explicity give them via `-I` it prints out these errors that i have not been able to get rid of:

````
    C:/msys64/mingw64/include\process.h:36:40: error: expected ';' after top level declarator [clang-diagnostic-error]
      _CRTIMP void __cdecl _endthread(void) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                                          ^
                                          ;
    C:/msys64/mingw64/include\process.h:38:54: error: expected ';' after top level declarator [clang-diagnostic-error]
      _CRTIMP void __cdecl _endthreadex(unsigned _Retval) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                                                        ^
                                                        ;
    C:/msys64/mingw64/include\process.h:42:47: error: expected ';' after top level declarator [clang-diagnostic-error]
      void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW exit(int _Code) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                                                  ^
                                                  ;
    C:/msys64/mingw64/include\process.h:43:48: error: expected ';' after top level declarator [clang-diagnostic-error]
      void __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _exit(int _Code) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                                                  ^
                                                  ;
    C:/msys64/mingw64/include\process.h:50:26: error: expected ';' after top level declarator [clang-diagnostic-error]
      void __cdecl _Exit(int) __MINGW_ATTRIB_NORETURN;
                            ^
```                            ;
````

Comment: Add `-- -isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include` last when running clang-tidy.

Comment: unistd.h is not a C standard header file, it's a header file for POSIX functions. C:/msys64/mingw64/include is a mingw subsystem path, clang-tidy is not aware of it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo @273K
I have already added `-- -Itictactoe_c/include/ -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include` at the end to get it to recognize my other include file as well as the unistd header. If I don't then it just says that it cant find the header obviously. But if I DO add them then I get the above error.

Even if I turn that into `-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include` I still get that error.

Comment: How have you obtained clang-tidy?

Comment: @273K, thanks that was it. I was somehow using one from something xcode related instead of the MinGW version.